# setDate method within another var returning a different value

Tags: javascript, date

How come these are not the same?:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(3);
console.log(now) //returns formatted date depending on current date
```

And ...

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.setDate(3);
console.log(day) //returns just numbers
```

??!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy4nwzyw/)

Comment: the value returned is the same in both. one logs the assignment "return", the other logs the whole object after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Because setDate returns what it's supposed to, which is the [number of milliseconds from epoch](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp).

> Return Value: A Number, representing the number of milliseconds
>   between the date object and midnight January 1 1970

Comment: Correct, whereas asking for the `Date()` object itself returns the fully-formatted date, as *it* should.